# Не удается установить mono-gmcs.

Tags: linux, kali-linux

```
apt-get install mono-gmcs

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово

Построение дерева зависимостей       

Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово

Пакет mono-gmcs недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.

Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из 

источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

Однако следующие пакеты могут его заменить:

  mono-xbuild mono-mcs mono-devel

E: Для пакета «mono-gmcs» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Не устанавливается пакет mono-gmcs. Kali Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pkgs.org/download/mono-gmcs говорит, что версий под свежие версии ubuntu и debian нету.

Если добавить официальный репозиторий в `trusty`:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list

apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

Обновить индексы и посмотреть инфу о пакете, то во второй строке будет вот такая инфа:

```
This is a transitional dummy package to aid migration to mono-mcs.
```

В общем смотри какому релизу убунты\дебиана соответствует твой Kali, добавляй строку выше и ставь `mono-mcs`.

Answer (score 0):

Пакет mono-gmcs недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.
Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

Однако следующие пакеты могут его заменить:

- mono-xbuild
- mono-mcs
- mono-devel

Comment: Установил эти пакеты, пишет, что не было произведено никаких обновлений. `apt-get install mono-devel
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет mono-devel самой новой версии (4.6.2.7+dfsg-1).
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 117 пакетов не обновлено.`

Comment: @NaGGaN, и чего именно теперь не хватает для счастья?